# SQL Server double to decimal read problem

Tags: c#, sql-server

from front end application I am sending the value as 0.15 to database via a stored procedure, but it gets stored as 0 value. Why? please guide. I am using C# + ASP.NET + SQL Server 2008

Comment: What are we supposed to do? Use a crystal ball to help you? Provide the complete code for those parts - the SP, the c# code and the table DDL for the field, please. Oh, and I had to give you even a sensible topic. What about putting ONE second effort into a question?

Comment: Can you **please** show us (a) the table structure, (b) the interface for the stored procedure (its list of parameters), and (c) the code snippet in your C# code that calls that stored procedure??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What datatype does the column have that you store it into? Also: what datatype does the parameter of the stored procedure have that you use to pass in that value??

My hunch: if you use e.g. `DECIMAL`  then you're using `DECIMAL(18,0)` --> up to 18 digits, but none after the decimal point. That would truncate 0.15 to 0. Just using `DECIMAL` as a data type doesn't automatically make it support after-decimal-point digits (a common mistake a lot of SQL programmers make - once - and then they know it).

Make sure both the parameter of the stored proc and the column in the table allow for fractional values, e.g. are something like `DECIMAL(18,4)` or something like that

Comment: @Lalit: just DECIMAL = DECIMAL(18,0) with **no** digits after the decimal point will **not** work. You need to expcitliy specify DECIMAL(18,2) or something like that - with digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure somewhere in your code your having an int / integer and this is where it get rounded to 0